# How to mask clouds from Python numpy array for a linear regression model?

Tags: python, numpy

I intend to build a linear regression model between two images, but I need to mask clouds first.

Based on some discussions, a masked array may be helpful (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#the-numpy-ma-module).

However, this is not what I want, because the function seems to mask missing values (e.g. clouds) as 0, rather than getting rid of it.

Here is my test by random numbers. I used scikit-learn for the regression model as the benchmark. Then, I added noises and mask noises by a masked array.

```
import numpy as num
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy.ma as ma

#the initial array
a=num.array([7,1,10,5,4,5,9,9,3,3])
b=num.array([10,9,3,4,7,7,8,1,10,9])
a=a.reshape(10,1)
b=b.reshape(10,1)
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(a,b)
regr.coef_ #-0.616504854
regr.intercept_ #10.25242718

#add noise by 0
a=num.array([7,1,10,0,5,4,5,0,9,9,3,3])
b=num.array([10,9,3,0,4,7,7,0,8,1,10,9])
a=a.reshape(12,1)
b=b.reshape(12,1)
maa = ma.masked_array(a, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1,0, 0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
mbb = ma.masked_array(b, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1,0, 0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(maa,mbb)
regr.coef_ #0.09405941
regr.intercept_ #5.22772279
```

Any hint to reach my goal? My goal is to delete points in the image, instead of viewing as 0.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Do you want to eliminate points in your images? Why do you want to perform a linear regression between two images?

Comment: @phyrox yes, I want to get rid of points in the image, which are labeled by clouds. I am working on image pre-processing. The coefficient and intercept of a linear regression are components of a equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from Scipy API for Masked array operations. Here is the page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html

Either ma.compressed(x) or ma.MaskedArray.compressed() can eliminate those missing values. 
Here is the revised code.

```
#add noise by 0
a=num.array([7,1,10,0,5,4,5,0,9,9,3,3])
b=num.array([10,9,3,0,4,7,7,0,8,1,10,9])
a=a.reshape(12,1)
b=b.reshape(12,1)
maa = ma.masked_array(a, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1,0, 0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
mbb = ma.masked_array(b, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1,0, 0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
maa=ma.compressed(maa).reshape(10,1)
mbb=ma.compressed(mbb).reshape(10,1)
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(maa,mbb)
regr.coef_ #-0.616504854
regr.intercept_ #10.25242718
```